# Initialization 2D Vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I want to take input from user for a 2D matrix by 2D vector. But while I'm doing like below, program crashed!!! But why?

```
int m, n;
cin>>m>>n;

vector<vector<int> > v;

for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
     for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
     {
         int a;
         cin>>a;
         v[i].push_back(a);
     }
}
```

What will be the solution according to my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the point where `v[i].push_back(a);` is called inside the `for` loop, vector `v` is empty and using `v[i]` will lead to undefined behaviour.

Your code should first `push_back` a `vector<int>`:

```
for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    v.push_back(vector<int>());
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        v[i].push_back(a);
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to initialize vector `v` explicitly to size `m`:

```
int m, n;
cin>>m>>n;
vector<vector<int> > v(m);

for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
     for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
     {
         int a;
         cin>>a;
         v[i].push_back(a);
     }
}
```

Comment: It works. Can you please give me details ans why I have to push_back a vector<int>??

Comment: @NafeeurRahman Because you didn't push_back anything into `v` and it's just empty. `v` is a 2-d vector.

Comment: @NafeeurRahman If vector `v` is empty, then accessing `v[i]` for any `i` will attempt to access memory outside the storage allocated (if any) for elements of `v`, which is undefined behaviour. For an analogy, this is similar to the case where you have `int v[10];` and you attempt to access `v[99]`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you know the size of your matrix just resize v before you fill it :

```
vector<vector<int> > v(m);
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    v[i].resize(n);
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        cin >> v[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

v[i] hasn't been constructed when you call v[i].push_back(),you just need to init v first.it's simple:

```
vector<vector<int>> v;
v.reserve(m);
for(...)
...
```